# Populate Telerik drop down list based on what is selected in other Telerik list

Tags: javascript, telerik

I have two Telerik drop down list. When any other country expect United States is selected I want the other drop down list to say 'Outside the US'. I am working on a JavaScript function but what I want to happen is not happening.

```
State:  <br />
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="State" runat="server" OnClientItemSelected="Selecting">
    <Items>
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Outside of US" Value="1" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Alabama"  /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Alaska" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Arizona" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Arkansas" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="California" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Colorado" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Connecticut" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Delaware" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="District Of Columbia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Florida" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Georgia" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Hawaii" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Idaho" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Illinois" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Indiana" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Iowa" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Kansas" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Kentucky" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Louisiana" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Maine" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Maryland" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Massachusetts" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Michigan" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Minnesota" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Mississippi" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Montana" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Nebraska" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Nevada" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="New Hampshire" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="New Jersey" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="New Mexico" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="New York" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="North Carolina" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="North Dakota" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Ohio" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Oklahoma" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Oregon" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Pennsylvania" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Rhode Island" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="South Carolina" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="South Dakota" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Tennessee" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Texas" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Utah" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Vermont" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Virginia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Washington" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="West Virginia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Wisconsin" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Wyoming" /> 
    </Items>       
</telerik:RadDropDownList> 
<br />  
Country:  <br />
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="Country" runat="server" OnClientItemSelected="Selecting">
    <Items>
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="United States" Value="1" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Afghanistan"  /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Åland Islands" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Albania" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Algeria" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Andorra" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Angola" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Anguilla" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Antigua and Barbuda" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Argentina" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Armenia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Aruba" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Australia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Austria" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Azerbaijan" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bahamas" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bahrain" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bangladesh" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Barbados" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Belarus" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Belgium" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Belize" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Benin" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bermuda" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bhutan" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bolivia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Botswana" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Brazil" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Bulgaria" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Burundi" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Cambodia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Cameroon" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Canada" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Central African Republic" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Chad" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Chile" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="China" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Colombia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Congo" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Costa Rica" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Côte d'Ivoire" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Croatia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Cuba" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Czech Republic" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Denmark" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Djibouti" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Dominica" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Dominican Republic" /> 
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Ecuador" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Egypt" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="El Salvador" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Estonia" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Ethiopia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Fiji" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Finland" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="France" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Georgia" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Germany" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Ghana" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Gibraltar" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Greece" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Greenland" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Grenada" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Guam" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Guatemala" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Haiti" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Holy See (Vatican City State)" /><telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Honduras" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Hong Kong" /> <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Hungary" /><telerik:DropDownListItem

    </Items>  
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Selecting(sender, eventArgs){
        var Country = $find("<% = Country.ClientID %>");
        var CountryDR = Country.get_selectedItem().get_text();
        var State = $find("<% = State.ClientID %>");
        if (CountryDR != "United States"){
            var item = State.findItemByText("Outside of US");
            item.select();
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: What is happening? Is your javascript running and not working or failing to run? You may want to add some console.log() calls to see the values of your variables or step through the js to make sure everything is as you expect it to be.

Comment: It is running but the second drop down list is not getting populated. I have added breakpoints to see what the values are at given times. @user15741

Comment: What does State.findItemByText("Outside of US"); evaluate to in your console? Can you findItemByValue(1) and get a different result?